# Access Log Timespan

Tags: logs

How can I output first and last time of an access_log so that I can quickly check which time range access_log keep records between?
Output may look like:

```
[21/Aug/2014:06:29:41 -0400] :::: [21/Aug/2014:10:29:41 -0400]
```

My access_log path is:

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log
```

Example Access Log Entry:

```
123.123.123.123 - - [21/Aug/2014:08:12:30 -0400] "GET /wp-content/themes/simple/comment-style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6221 "http://example.com/?p=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your log entries are not in strict chronological order, on a GNU system, you can do:

```
#          1         2
# 12345678901234567890
# [21/Aug/2014:06:29:41 -0400]

< access.log sed -n 's/^[^[]*\(\[[^]]*]\).*/\1/p' |
  sort -k1.9n -k1.5M -k1.2n -k1.14,1.21 |
  sed -n '1p;$p' | paste -sd -
```

The result is probably going to be wrong one day per year upon the switch between summer time and winter time.

Comment: Thanks. Result is: `[en]-[21/Aug/2014:12:13:04 -0400]` End date is correct but start time shows as "en". I updated my question to add an example access log entry.

Comment: @NecNecco, OK, I've updated the answer to return the first `[...]` set only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '1p;$p' /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log
```

Or `awk`

```
awk 'NR==1;END{print}' /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log
```

There are other methods too using `tail` and `head`

Comment: Access log entries are not always in chronological order (as several apache processes write to it).

Comment: (the time span of two access logs rotated by logrorate may actually overlap as well)